# any library function that provides the function of wait in objective c

Tags: objective-c

HI
    I want to use a function that do the work as of wait() in obj.C .(not NSTimer coz i dont want to call any function all that i want is to wait for a few seconds and then display images after each other.

Comment: `wait()` does not do what you think it does.  I'm pretty sure you are really talking about `sleep()`.

Answer (score 3):

Use `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:` !
wait() will freeze your app !!!

Answer (score 2):

wait() is a function. If you don't want to call a function then you can't achieve what you want, or indeed pretty much anything else. But I guess you mean that you don't want an actor that ends up calling a method on your class — you want a direct, inline pause? Then, you probably want:

```
[NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:timeInSeconds]; // e.g. 2.0 to sleep 2 seconds
```

EDIT: though, ideologically, I completely agree with Benoît. A perfect program shouldn't allow the UI thread to block at any point.

Comment: Thanx all for the responses i will try for the suggestions

Answer (score 0):

The key here is "display images".  If you try to draw an image, suspend the main thread (ack!) and then try to draw another one, you won't see the images anyway.

So you'll need to use an NSTimer or performSelector:...Delay:

These techniques allow your app's main thread to return to the run loop which is necessary to do any drawing at all.